# Проверка на существование строки в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Сейчас на страницу сайта выводится список из 15 городов, стоит задача выводить список городов в которых зарегистрирован хотя бы 1 пользователь на нашем сайте. То есть если нет ни одной строчки в `MySQL`, в которой поле `gorod = Moscow`. То город Москва в списке не выводится. Есть какая - нибудь специальная функция для этого? Есть решение, но я думаю оно не рационально: подсчитывать строки с определенным условием и после сравнивать количество строк с нулем и выводить соответствующий результат.

Comment: какова структура таблиц с городами и юзерами?

Comment: @fStrange все в одной таблице.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE `sity` = 'Moscow' ");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$total = $row[0]; // всего записей
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `city`
FROM `users`
GROUP BY `city`
```

Выведет список городов, упоминаемых хотя бы раз.

Comment: зачем `having`?

Comment: @KaZaца затем, что утро, но без кофе : ) Вы правы, всё проще. Исправил.